# Adding subscripts to tick labels (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to include a subscript 2 in my tick labels, but I cannot seem to make it work. Here is the most recent code that I have tried out:

[All the relevant code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyTFk.png)

As you can see, the subscript turns out fine when pasting the vector. The ggplot2 code returns the following plot:

[My plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7gIf.png)

The subscript 2 just appears as a blank square. Any input will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `expression`, here an example:

```
tibble(x = 1,y = 1) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = 1,y = 1))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = 1,
    labels = expression(paste("Ambient ",CO[2]))
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Glad it helped you, could please close the question? This helps further searches!